# Most efficient way to to search for lines with a substring match in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a list of names with noise and a list of clean names, I am sure that the clean names are an exact substring of the names with noise.

Lets say we have a name with noise, for example `var?goldenfoo`, and I would like to output, from a text file `cleannames` which looks like this

```
golden
blue
red
```

`golden`.

I have tried using grep to the `cat`ed `cleannames`, but this seems rather unneficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
grep -Fof cleannames.txt text.txt
```

If you want something else, just edit your question and add more details. :)

let say have this:

> Impedit quas et totam in omnis. Voluptas repellat voluptas possimus
>   rerum est **golden**nihil. Et ut minima sit. Quia accusamus rerum
>   voluptate. Dolores molestiae non dolorem dignissimos quaerat magni.
>   Quia reiciendis cupi**golden**ditate quo hic doloremque molestiae. Odio
>   odio quis est quisquam eligendi esse. Quo natus architecto in id
>   dolorum eveniet. Modi error dolorum voluptas ul**red**lam aut. Soluta
>   veniam corporis est. Illum maxime**golden** perferendis incidunt qui
>   consequatur. Laborum quia ab voluptatem.

will print

```
golden
golden
red
golden
```

and the

```
echo 'var?goldenfoo' | grep -Fof cleannames.txt
```

will print

```
golden
```

or

```
clean=(golden red blue)  #or read into array from a file...
text='var?goldenfoo'

grep -Fof <(printf "%s\n" "${clean[@]}") <<< "$text"
```

prints

```
golden
```

so you can instead of the `cleannames.txt` have any process substitution and also instead of the `text.txt` you can have any redirection. Any combination will work.

Comment: Names are not stored in a file, they are a variable.

Comment: cleannames is a file, but name `var?goldenfoo` **is not**.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep clean names in an array using `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t ary < cleannames
```

then use a search function like this:

```
srch() { for i in "${ary[@]}"; do [[ $1 == *"$i"* ]] && echo "$i"; done; }
```

Then invoke it as:

```
srch 'var?goldenfoo'
golden

srch 'foobar?bluebox'
blue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search faster than grep you should give the 
[Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) a try.